# nodeJS + MongoDB + Mongoose - Unable To Delete 1 Entry

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using nodeJS MongoDB/Mongoose to create/update/delete movies inside the database using Postman post/delete methods.
The create function is working fine, and even the remove function is working properly so when I use Postman I get the return: "Movie has been deleted!" like it should.

The only problem is that my function is emptying the entire database of movies instead of just that 1 movie, here is the remove function:

```
 function destroy(req, res, next){
    var movieID = req.body
            Movie.remove(movieID, function(err,movie){
                    if(err){
                        res.status(400).send(err)
                    } else {
                        res.send("Movie has been deleted!")
                        db.close()
                    }
            })
```

The movie object:

```
var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    yay: Number,
    nay: Number,
    release_date: Date,
    in_theaters: Boolean,
    released: Boolean,
    buy_link: String,
    imdb_link: String,
    image_url: String,
    description: String,
    trailer_link: String
})
```

**I want to delete a movie based on it's "name" so I only have to input the name and it will delete the entire movie.**

Comment: Is this correct   var movieID = req.body ?   I think it might be like this:  var movieID = req.body.movieID;

Comment: Before db.close(), add one line console.log(movie); if movie contains n : 1, then it removed 1 record from DB. it it is 0, then nothing happened.

Comment: Alternatively, you can enable debug mode of mongoose, mongoose.set('debug', true); which prints the every query to mongodb.

Comment: Yeah it responds to the remove function because when I get the entire index of the movieDB it's empty. 
I tried what you said as well and it said 1.

Comment: @HirenS. Thanks for the suggestions, I'm gonna try them!

Comment: I missed the last line. if you want to remove by name you need to do like this: Movie.remove({ "name" : "MOVIE_NAME_HERE"}, function(err,movie){

Comment: @HirenS. Thanks, but can I define the "MOVIE_NAME_HERE" Part outside the server? I want to put in the name in postman and have the server remove the movie, not hard-code it into the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [findOneAndRemove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndRemove) query?

This query is much cleaner compared to finding a model and removing it inside the callback. Beside this I assume it's faster because you basically do 1 query instead of 2 after each other.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
    var movieName = req.body.name;
    Movie.find('name': movieName, function(err, movie) {
        if (err) res.send({error: err});


        Movie.remove(function(err, movie){
            if (err) res.send({error: err});
            res.json({message: "Movie is removed", movie: movie});
        });

    });
```

Comment: Tried it, this also deletes all the movies inside the database.

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you please test that as well?

Comment: Tried it, it gives me a "not found" back when I use postman to do the following:

{
    "name": "Captain America: Civil War"
}

Comment: I'll try to fix it when I get home. Could you please share the way you call the destroy() function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing direct value to Remove method, it will try to match with _id field.

As per your model, _id is ObjectId field which is managed automatically by mongodb.
In case if you enter like this. `.remove("movie", callback)` which is not a valid ObjectId.

Mongoose is discarding this invalid condition and executing Movie.remove({}); which is deleting all your records.

So it is better to validate whether the input is valid ObjectId or not before directly passing to Movie.remove();

I also recommend to use like this: `Movie.remove({_id: movieId}, callback)`.
And for movie name :

```
Movie.remove({name: movieName}, callback);
```

Update:
You can take from Postman

```
var movieName = req.body.movieName;

Movie.remove({name: movieName}, function(err, updateObj){
});
```